# Работа с несколькими моделями из одной формы в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Как связать две таблицы с одной формой ввода в Yii2? 
Есть две таблицы "Игра" и "Скриншоты". Требуется заполнить эти данные с одной формы.

Comment: [Тут](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/input-multiple-models/) хорошее объяснение, вы его читали?

Comment: после него я и обратился сюда, не совсем понятно, что и куда писать, какие файлы редактировать